# Error while opening Jmeter Plugin Manager

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I just added the plugin manager jar(jmeter-plugins-manager-0.10) in lib/ext folder of Jmeter(3.0). I keep getting this error when I try to open Plugin Manager through the Options. Can someone please help.

I tried to run the jmeter through command prompt using Jmeter.bat -H my-proxy-server -P portnumber but this also not worked

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: jmeter-plugins.org
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1248)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1164)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:262)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.getJSON(PluginManager.java:149)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:78)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerDialog.componentShown(PluginManagerDialog.java:178)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentShown(AWTEventMulticaster.java:179)
    at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6348)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6296)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2022)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuItem.actionPerformed(PluginManagerMenuItem.java:41)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error however after specifying the proxy in jmeter.sh, it worked fine.

```
JVM_ARGS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=MyProxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyUser=MyUserName -Dhttp.proxyPass=Password"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging from the machine where you run jmeter the site:

> ping jmeter-plugins.org

Your error here is that the DNS does not even know this website

Comment: I tried it but got this error -'Ping request could not find host jmeter-plugins.org. Please check the name and try again.'.

Comment: So it confirms issue is in your system (Windows or Linux) where it does not seem to be connected to a valid DNS server

Comment: Thanks for the response.In addition i even tried to ping -'google.com' but got the same issue. Any idea?

Comment: Check that you machine is connected to the network. It's no more a JMeter question, it's OS one or install one. If answer is ok u should accept it and upvote