# Taurus Execution failure via yaml scripts for jmeter jmx scripts behind proxy

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, taurus

I am trying to execute some jmeter jmx scripts using Tarus via yaml scripts named "ParallelExecution.yml".

Yaml Script:

```
execution:
   - executor: jmeter
execution:
- scenario:
    script: C:\Users\SampleScripts\WSO2ServiceAPI.jmx
- scenario:
    script: C:\Users\SampleScripts\KongServiceAPI.jmx
reporting:
 - module: blazemeter
   report-name: TaurusPerformanceTest
   test: WSO2andKong
   project: SampleProject
```

But, its fetching the following error after I execute the command "bzt ParallelExecution.yml -report".

```
C:\Users\YmlScripts>bzt ParallelExecution.yml
12:38:28 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.13.8
12:38:28 INFO: Starting with configs: ['ParallelExecution.yml']
12:38:28 INFO: Configuring...
12:38:28 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\Users\YmlScripts\2019-11-09_12-38-28.188921
12:38:28 INFO: Preparing...
12:38:28 WARNING: Failed to check for updates
12:38:29 INFO: 1 obsolete CookieManagers are found and fixed
12:38:36 WARNING: Failed to detect plugins for C:\Users\SampleScripts\modified_WSO2ServiceAPI.jmx: Command '['C:\\Users\\.bzt\\jmeter-taurus\\5.1.1\\bin\\PluginsManagerCMD.bat', 'install-for-jmx', 'C:\\Users\\SampleScripts\\modified_WSO2ServiceAPI.jmx']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

>>> START OF STDOUT >>>
2019-11-09 12:38:31,632 INFO o.j.r.PluginManagerCMD: Command is: install-for-jmx
2019-11-09 12:38:32,697 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Requesting https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/?installID=docker-64602d8e8eb9f2a1a3b0804261cdb5e6-nongui

<<< END OF STDOUT <<<

>>> START OF STDERR >>>
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to perform cmdline operation: jmeter-plugins.org
*** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: C:\Users\.bzt\jmeter-taurus\5.1.1\lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to perform cmdline operation: jmeter-plugins.org
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.processParams(PluginManagerCMD.java:100)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:62)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:115)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jmeter-plugins.org
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.execute(JARSourceHTTP.java:499)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.execute(JARSourceHTTP.java:494)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getJSON(JARSourceHTTP.java:152)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getRepositories(JARSourceHTTP.java:276)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getRepo(JARSourceHTTP.java:304)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:71)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.getPluginsManager(PluginManagerCMD.java:110)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.installPluginsForJmx(PluginManagerCMD.java:120)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.processParams(PluginManagerCMD.java:79)
        ... 7 more

<<< END OF STDERR <<<

12:38:36 INFO: 1 obsolete CookieManagers are found and fixed
12:38:46 WARNING: Failed to detect plugins for C:\Users\SampleScripts\modified_KongServiceAPI.jmx: Command '['C:\\Users\\.bzt\\jmeter-taurus\\5.1.1\\bin\\PluginsManagerCMD.bat', 'install-for-jmx', 'C:\\Users\\SampleScripts\\modified_KongServiceAPI.jmx']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

>>> START OF STDOUT >>>
2019-11-09 12:38:39,605 INFO o.j.r.PluginManagerCMD: Command is: install-for-jmx
2019-11-09 12:38:42,035 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Requesting https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/?installID=docker-64602d8e8eb9f2a1a3b0804261cdb5e6-nongui

<<< END OF STDOUT <<<

>>> START OF STDERR >>>
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to perform cmdline operation: jmeter-plugins.org
*** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: C:\Users\.bzt\jmeter-taurus\5.1.1\lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to perform cmdline operation: jmeter-plugins.org
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.processParams(PluginManagerCMD.java:100)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:62)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:115)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jmeter-plugins.org
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.execute(JARSourceHTTP.java:499)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.execute(JARSourceHTTP.java:494)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getJSON(JARSourceHTTP.java:152)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getRepositories(JARSourceHTTP.java:276)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getRepo(JARSourceHTTP.java:304)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:71)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.getPluginsManager(PluginManagerCMD.java:110)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.installPluginsForJmx(PluginManagerCMD.java:120)
        at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.processParams(PluginManagerCMD.java:79)
        ... 7 more

<<< END OF STDERR <<<

12:38:46 WARNING: No BlazeMeter API key provided, will upload anonymously
12:38:46 ERROR: Network Error: Request to https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/web/version failed
12:38:46 INFO: Post-processing...
12:38:46 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:00
12:38:46 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\Users\YmlScripts\2019-11-09_12-38-28.188921
12:38:46 WARNING: Done performing with code: 1
```

I am not sure why I taurus is not able to execute the script. It runs correctly as jmeter scripts via jmeter.
Any help would be highly appreticated

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722910/error-while-opening-jmeter-plugin-manager

Answer (score 4):

Looking into this line:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jmeter-plugins.org
```

It appears that the underlying [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) is not able to reach [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) backend, presumably this is due to the fact you're using [corporate proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) for the internet access.

You can [configure Taurus to use the proxy](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#Top-Level-Settings) of your choice by adding the next lines to your YAML config file:

```
settings:
  proxy:
    address: http://localhost:8080
    username: johndoe
    password: secret
```

of course replace `address`, `username` and `password` with your own values. Once done - restart the test and Taurus will propagate proxy settings to the downstream JMeter. JMeter Plugins Manager respects JMeter proxy settings so you should be able to execute the test normally.

Just in case check out [Plugins Manager Network Configuration](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/) page.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thank you!
The above solution worked for connecting to jmeter-plugins.org after appending the required certificate.
But,I am still facing 
12:38:28 WARNING: Failed to check for updates
12:38:46 ERROR: Network Error: Request to https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/web/version failed

and couldn't proceed with the executions on Taurus.