# Jmeter failed to download plugins repository

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to use jmeter on a working machine without internet access. I installed Apache Jmeter 5.2.1 myself, downloaded plugins-manager.jar and put it into lib / ext directory, then restarted JMeter.

But when I try to go to Jmeter -> Options -> Plugins Manager, I see this error:

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722910/error-while-opening-jmeter-plugin-manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need add Plugins(jars) to the system without Internet Connection you have to manually download them on another system with internet connect and then you can move the jars to

Jmeter (Folder)
   |->Lib (Folder)
   |->ext (Folder)

Paste the Jars into the ext folder and restart the Jmeter can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[UnknownHostException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) means that the Plugins Manager is not able to get the address of the plugins repository.

Most probably your machine doesn't have direct Internet connection and requires a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) in order to reach to the external hosts.

You need to configure JMeter to use your corporate proxy address, port and in some cases username and password, it can be done in 2 ways:

1. Via JMeter [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -E https -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost
   ```
2. Via *system.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

   ```
   http.proxyHost=my.proxy.server
   http.proxyPort=8080
   https.proxyHost=my.proxy.server 
   https.proxyPort=8080
   ```

JMeter Plugins Manager respects JMeter's proxy settings so given you're able to successfully execute HTTP Request samplers you should be able to download the plugins as well.

References:

- [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)
- [Plugins Manager Network Configuration -> Using Behind the Proxy](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/#Using-Behind-the-Proxy)

Comment: using proxy only some corporate sites work. Alas, access to everything else is blocked by corporate policies. At the moment, I solved my question as follows: I moved the lib folder from the computer where everything works to the working computer. This solved the problem.